# Instanciar um objeto durante todo o ciclo de vida da aplicação em Java

Tags: java, amazon-aws

Tenho uma aplicação aqui em Java que usa o SDK da Amazon para enviar imagens para um bucket S3.

Pra fazer isso eu utilizo threads, basicamente está modelado da seguinte maneira:

A classe `Mai`n tem uma lista de threads e cada item da lista é enviado para uma classe Executora e esta chama uma classe `Callable` que baixa uma imagem e retorna as informações da imagem para a executora que faz o upload da imagem.

O problema que toda vez que vou enviar a imagem tenho que me conectar ao bucket. Vejam:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Usuario", "Senha");
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
```

Alguém sabe me dizer uma maneira de eu instanciar esses objetos de conexão na `Main` para quando eu chegar no `Executor` na hora de enviar eu já esteja conectado?

Comment: Você está rodando a aplicação local ou é uma instância EC2?

Comment: A aplicação eu rodo da minha máquina mesmo.

Comment: [Configure suas credenciais](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/) na máquina, dai você não precisa ficar informando usuário e senha hard coded. E se for subir sua aplicação pra uma intância EC2, basta dar permissão de acesso ao S3 via IAM.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim terei que conectar toda hora. O que eu preciso é  realizar essa operação de conectar apenas uma vez.

Comment: Ah entendi...Basta você passar a instância da classe AmazonS3 para sua classe executora. Defina um construtor na classe executora que recebe um argumento do tipo AmazonS3, provável que resolva.

Comment: Você não pode usar um _Singleton_? (embora eu ache que manter uma conexão aberta seja uma ideia ruim)

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Ele pode! Não existe "conexão" aberta, é apenas um Http Request sem Keep Alive.

Comment: O usuário e a senha são fixos?

Comment: São fixos, obrigado pela resposta amigo, daqui a pouco vou tentar aqui!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, encapsule a criação do `AmazonS3`:

```
private static AmazonS3 criarClient(String usuario, String senha) {
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(usuario, senha);

    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
        .build();
}
```

E então, se o usuário e senha forem fixos, você pode fazer isso:

```
private static final AmazonS3 CLIENT = criarClient("Usuário", "Senha");
```

O objeto `AmazonS3` é thread-safe e imutável. Assim sendo, se o usuário e senha forem fixos, você pode seguramente colocá-lo em uma variável estática uma única vez quando a sua classe em questão está sendo carregada, mesmo se houver várias threads envolvidas

Se o usuário e senha não forem fixos, basta utilizar o método `criarClient` uma vez para cada login/senha que você for utilizar, mesmo que as instâncias venham a ser utilizadas concorrentemente por várias threads.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas pra esclarecer alguns pontos que ficaram um pouco confusos:

Não existe "estar conectado no bucket", o que a aws sdk está fazendo é pegando suas credenciais para assinar o request, você está trabalhando com http requests (sem keep alive).

Um exemplo simples:

```
public class AmazonS3Worker implements Runnable {

    private AmazonS3 s3;

    public AmazonS3Worker(AmazonS3 s3) {
        this.s3 = s3;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //download com s3.getObject

    }

}
```

e na Main:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Usuario", "Senha");
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new AmazonS3Worker(s3client);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    while(!executor.isTerminated()) {}
    System.out.println("Done!");

}
```

Comment: Então Tom, na verdade minhas classes estão estruturadas de uma maneira um pouco diferente, pois na classe Main eu chamo uma classe que implementa Runnable, dessa forma eu teria que passar pra ela o objeto já instanciado.... Mas obrigado pela dica!